# How to do group_by in Tidymodel Recipes

Tags: r, recipe, tidymodels

I would like to do something like this using the recipes package in Tidymodels:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(RespID) %>%
  mutate(Col5 = as.integer(all(c('A', 'B') %in% Col4) & Col4 == 'A')) %>%
  ungroup
```

I am able to run something with `step_mutate`, however cannot use the `group_by` functionality. How can I incorporate the process I'm taking in the script above into Tidymodel Recipes?

```
recipe <- recipe( ~ field1 + field2 + field3, data = training) %>%
  step_mutate(response= as.factor(all(c('A', 'B') %in% Col4) & Col4 == 'A'), role="outcome")
```

Comment: Can you save the output of `dplyr` code that gives the output you want in another variable (say `df1`) and then use it in `recipe` directly instead of using `step_mutate` ?

Comment: This is not possible in `recipes` right now. There is a discussion and call for use-cases in this issue https://github.com/tidymodels/recipes/issues/166.

Comment: I'm super late to this party, but a clear use case for this is performing Box-Cox transformations across index values in a panel dataset. I know that panel data has been discussed in various comments in the GitHub issue, but BoxCox is a very specific use case given that the lambda value needs to be calculated by index group or stratum. But the issue is closed now :(